# Returning wrong order in SOQL ORDER BY

Tags: soql, formula, query

I'm facing a problem with the SOQL `ORDER BY`. I'm quering on a custom object with this query

```
SELECT completeTreeSequence__c 
FROM CPQ_Line__c 
WHERE CPQ_Header_RU__r.Id = 'a043E000005PfD7QAK' 
ORDER BY completeTreeSequence__c ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

where `completeTreeSequence__c` is a text formula field

this is the result:

[image]

Results are wrong beacuse the item 5--> "1.1.2.1.10" should be after the item 6 -->"1.1.2.1.1.1".

I think the "10" is interpreted as "1" and this is why it comes with the wrong order.

Does anyone has faced this error and solved it?

Comment: For reference, the reason the sort order appears this way is because of lexicographical ordering.

Answer (score 2):

This ordering is actually correct because the field type is `text`. It will be same whichever language (database/server/javascript) you do a sort. Since you have multiple `dots`, you cannot even set the data type as `number`. The only option is to get the records and write a custom logic to sort them correctly.

**adding based on comments:**

Adding `0` still is failing:

```
var nums = ["01.02.01", "01.02.08", "01.02.011"];
nums.sort(); // 01.02.01, 01.02.011, 01.02.08
```

Comment: Problem is that in UTF table dot comes before zero or one (f.e. https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl), so basically questions is valid. I am able to reproduce it

Comment: Yes, question is valid. I just said that the `Order By` is behaving correctly since the data type is text.

Comment: i tried to create folders on windows with the same name of that field value and the order is correct right there.
Also i've solved the issue padding left to 2 digits with '0'

Comment: Windows will have custom logic to deal with file names. I didnt understand what you mean by `padding left to 2 digits with '0'`

Comment: I've changed the formula that creates that field.

Before was 1.10 comes before 1.1.1 ---

Now is 01.10 and 01.01.01 and the order is correct as 01.01.01 comes before 01.10

Comment: That will still fail.. added in answer

Comment: if u manage to have 2 digits maximum you will have to pad to 2 digit. So 11 remains 11 and not 011. i will add my results on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved using a workaround padding every element of the string to 2 digits adding '0' to the left.

now 1.1.1 is sorted before 1.10 as i was expecting

[image]